# Mac Catalyst App with Firebase won't receive push notifications

Tags: ios, macos, firebase, push-notification, mac-catalyst

I have an iOS app with push notifications set up and the feature is working fine on iOS devices. I now build a Mac Catalyst app of my iOS app and I was trying to get the push notifications to work but it doesn't work.

I'm receiving the registration token in `func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging,didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String)` but I'm not able to get any push notifications.

In the settings app on the Mac I also see that my app is set up for notifications.

Am I missing something out?

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure about Firebase, but [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com) introduced support for Catalyst Push notifications. In case Firebase doesn't work out, you can try using OneSignal for Mac push by following the instructions [here](https://onesignal.com/blog/onesignal-supports-mac-catalyst-build/).